# How to hide text when array.length === 0

Tags: javascript, angular

So I want to hide the some text, when the array.length is 0.

So this is the template:

```
 <h3>{{ OkrSensoren }}</h3>
```

So I want to hide the text:  `<h3>{{ radarSensoren }}</h3>`

when radarSensors.length === 0

and this is ts script:

```
radarSensoren = 'Radar sensoren';
```

But it doesnt hide the text. And the array is emtpy:

```
radarSensors: Array(0)
length: 0
```

Comment: The code you posted does not appear to make any attempt at hiding the `<h3>` tag.

Comment: I think you will not get into <ng-template *ngIf="sensorStatusCollection.radarSensors.length === 0"> because the array length is 0.

Comment: `<h3 *ngIf="!!sensorStatusCollection.radarSensors.length">{{ radarSensoren }}</h3>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already apply the same kind of logic below, why do you not apply it at your "h3" tag ?

```
<h3 *ngIf="radarSensoren.length !== 0">{{ radarSensoren }}</h3>
```

Or

```
<h3 *ngIf="!!radarSensoren">{{ radarSensoren }}</h3>
```